# Openpyxl error: merged cell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Tags: python, automation, macros, openpyxl, rpa

I was trying to copy data from one excel sheet(.xlsm) to another(xlsm) macros enabled using openpyxl but I am getting ('MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only) error. It is working fine when I am copying data from datasheets which doesn't contain merged cells. How do I copy data from sheets having merged cells?

Here's my code snippet:

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows10, 3):
for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
ws10.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

Comment: Just skip merged cells.

Comment: How to do that? Syntax please :')